# Is Brandoo Wordpress safe for production environment?

Tags: sql-server, wordpress, azure

I have a Wordpress blog that is now running in Linux/MySQL. Now, I have seen a product called Brandoo Wordpress which let you run Wordpress on IIS + MSSQL.
Since I am using Windows Server and MSSQL for all my other projects I would very much like to use it on my Wordpress blog too. The wordpress site is quite big and important. The blog is beloved for its adult content. It has a revenue on thousands of dollars/month so I don't want to rush in anything here.

The Brandoo Wordpress is a part of the application gallery in Windows Platform Installer and also in Windows Azure.
So my questions are:
**Since Brandoo Wordpress is a part of the apps in Azure, do you think it is quality assured by Microsoft?
I guess before Microsoft adds a web app to Azure and Platform Installer it has to be safe and bug free? Right?**

I have tested my Wordpress locally with Brandoo Wordpress and it seems to work great so far.

Answer (score 4):

I'm member of Brandoo WordPress team and I think I can help You. So... Brandoo WordPress is based on MSSQL. If You are using plugins that uses non-standard (same for MS and My SQL)  db query You must face situation when You will must drop those plugins untill we will create translation for those queries that are not translated yet. There is also one thing. Brandoo WordPress is one step behind mainline right now. It's because some MySQL speciffic query in onsite search function. We do not want to fork WP and change it to MS schema so we are still working on translation or disabling this subfunction (If we willagree that this is a safe way to do it). If this is ok for You, then Brandoo WordPress is good for Your production.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this a guarantee, but one of the [principles of submission to the web app store](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/windows-web-application-gallery/windows-web-application-gallery-principles) is to "Be Safe"